# Showing that if X and Y are independent and have chf $\phi$, and distribution $\mu$, then a property holds.

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

[image]

Ex 3.3.2 is posted below:

[image]

Ex 2.1.5 says that $P(X - Y = 0) = 0$, which means $P(X = Y) = 0$ for $X$ having continuous distribution. I am not sure how to proceed and do this problem. $|\phi(t)|^{2}$ = $E^{2}$, since its chf or characteristic function and if you apply the formula of $\phi$, you get the desired result. But how can I compute that and tell that they are all same?

Would appreciate if someone helps me on this.

Ex 2.1.5 is posted below:

[image]

Comment: What does Exercise 3.3.2 say?

Comment: Pls check now, I have posted it there. You shud be able to see it

Comment: So, the first equality is precisely the conclusion of Exercise 3.3.2 (i) with $\mu$ the law of $X-Y$ and $a=0$.  And can you also post the text of Exercise 2.1.5?  I have a hunch it has more than what you wrote.

Comment: done with Ex 2.1.5....

Comment: Yeah.  So for the second equality, apply 2.1.5 (i), replacing $X$ by $-X$.  In short, 3.3.3 follows immediately from the previous exercises.

Comment: And for the first, apply the Exercise 3.3.2 to  $\mu_{X-Y}$, $\varphi_{X-Y}$ at $a=0$...